# How to setup GLFW for CLion using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide, glfw

This didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868427/7123519

[image]

---

This didn't work either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979876/10152089

Someone please show a minimum working example of "how to setup GLFW for CLion using CMake".

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect code and the error message to be in **textual** form, not as image. Please, [edit] your question post and copy paste the code and the error message as **text**.

Comment: Usually the solution is to do what the `CMake` error message says. With that said, I somewhat doubt that the CMakeLists.txt in the picture produced the error show in the error box. That error normally comes from find_package() but I unless I need my eyes checked I don't see a find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED) in the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, sorry, I forgot to rebuild it after deleting the "find_package()". It doesn't work with or without find_package()

Comment: My intention of the image was not for any to read, simply to give the reader a feel of what I have tried. I was hoping someone would show a minimal working example of GLFW in clion